# iOS Sliding Effect ViewControllers - Instagram Activity Tab

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My desired animation:
http://i.giphy.com/v8xYEICQMk7Ly.gif

I can already solve this without the sliding effect by having a Container and 2 different TableViews and showing the appropriate view when the "Following/You" buttons are tapped.

Any high level suggestions on what the approach is to do adding the sliding effect?
In case you don't have Instagram, the sliding effect feels just like a horizontal uicollectionview with bouncing allowed.

Comment: https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu

Comment: Wow, exactly what I wanted. Thank you! xoxo

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use UIScrollView with pagination enabled. You can either add the subviews programmatically or via storyboard. Then you set the scrollview's `contentSize = numberOfPage * eachPageWidth`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use UIPageViewController.
For reference you can refer the apple documentation : https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontroller